# How does Scala handle isnull or ifnull in query with sqlContext

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, isnull

I have two data files as below:

```
course.txt 
id,course 
1,Hadoop
2,Spark
3,HBase
5,Impala

Fee.txt 
id,amount 
2,3900
3,4200
4,2900
```

I need to list all course info with their fee:

```
sqlContext.sql("select c.id, c.course, f.amount from course c left outer join fee f on f.id = c.id").show
+---+------+------+
| id|course|amount|
+---+------+------+
|  1|Hadoop|  null|
|  2| Spark|3900.0|
|  3| HBase|4200.0|
|  5|Impala|  null|
+---+------+------+
```

if the course is not indicated in the Fee table, then instead of showing null, I want to show 'N/A'.

I've tried the following and not getting it yet:

command 1:

```
sqlContext.sql("select c.id, c.course, ifnull(f.amount, 'N/A') from course c left outer join fee f on f.id = c.id").show
```

**Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function ifnull; line 1 pos 40**

command 2:

```
sqlContext.sql("select c.id, c.course, isnull(f.amount, 'N/A') from course c left outer join fee f on f.id = c.id").show
```

**Error:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPNull because: The operator 'IS NULL' only accepts 1 argument..; line 1 pos 40**

What is the right way to handle this in sqlContext within Scala? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Spark DataFrame API, you can use `when/otherwise` with `isNull` condition:

```
val course = Seq(
  (1, "Hadoop"),
  (2, "Spark"),
  (3, "HBase"),
  (5, "Impala")
).toDF("id", "course")

val fee = Seq(
  (2, 3900),
  (3, 4200),
  (4, 2900)
).toDF("id", "amount")

course.join(fee, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  withColumn("amount", when($"amount".isNull, "N/A").otherwise($"amount")).
  show
// +---+------+------+
// | id|course|amount|
// +---+------+------+
// |  1|Hadoop|   N/A|
// |  2| Spark|  3900|
// |  3| HBase|  4200|
// |  5|Impala|   N/A|
// +---+------+------+
```

If you prefer using Spark SQL, here's an equivalent SQL:

```
course.createOrReplaceTempView("coursetable")
fee.createOrReplaceTempView("feetable")

val result = spark.sql("""
  select
    c.id, c.course,
    case when f.amount is null then 'N/A' else f.amount end as amount
  from
    coursetable c left outer join feetable f on f.id = c.id
""")
```

Comment: Thank you Leo, this is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

If it is spark SQL , use coalesce UDF

```
select 
  c.id, 
  c.course, 
  coalesce(f.amount, 'N/A') as amount 
from c 
left outer join f 
on f.id = c.id"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in *simple sql query* as the following using `if`, `isnull` functions and *N/A literal*

```
course.createOrReplaceTempView("c")
fee.createOrReplaceTempView("f")
sqlContext.sql("select c.id, c.course, if(isnull(f.amount), 'N/A', f.amount) as amount from c left outer join f on f.id = c.id").show
```

You should have the following output

```
+---+------+------+
| id|course|amount|
+---+------+------+
|  1|Hadoop|   N/A|
|  2| Spark|  3900|
|  3| HBase|  4200|
|  5|Impala|   N/A|
+---+------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataFrameNA functions. After the join has been done, you can replace all the nulls with a string using the DataFrameNA fill function

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html

Answer (score 0):

In sqlContext, use "NVL"

```
sqlContext.sql("""   
   SELECT c.id
      ,c.course
      ,NVL(f.amount, 'N/A')
      FROM course c
      LEFT OUTER
      JOIN fee f 
      ON f.id = c.id
    """).show()
```